What are the meanings of 'all' and 'only' in the paradox of the barber?
Barber's Paradox
In a certain town there is a barber who shaves all those who don't shave themselves, and only those who don't shave themselves.  Who shaves the barber?
Let b denote the barber. Let x-S-x be the propositional function "x shaves x".  The paradox is that
b-S-b if and only if not (b-S-b)
So my question is what is the exact meanings of 'all' and 'only' used to arrive at the paradox?
Aside:  I'm thinking 'all' has existential import, while 'any' does not.  If you hold this position too, then the proper translation of ∀ x [P(x)] would be "for any x, P of x", instead of "for all x, P of x".

I'm not seeing what's confusing about it. "All" and "only" have just their normal meanings. He shaved all those who don't shave themselves means that every single member of the set of people who don't shave themselves are shaved by him. Only means he doesn't shave anybody else outside of that set.

Does that mean that the town is a non empty set.  Your subconsciously assuming that

Am I assuming that? I don't see where that assumption comes in.

I want to know ultimately, is the resolution to the paradox that the town is empty?  The answer depends on the meanings of 'all' and 'only'.

If the town is empty there is no barber in the town.

The barber sentence is typically formalized with standard ∀x which, by modern convention, has no existential import. But naming the barber by a constant, b, also by modern convention, does have existential import. So the resolution of ∀x [S(b,x) ↔ ¬ S(x,x)] by empty town will not be available in your version.

@mauro, that's my conclusion.  No such barber can exist.

@conifold, that's the precise location of an open scope of an assumption..  It's assumed there exists a barber such that, etc.  then you use Existential Instantiation, and name him b.  Then when you arrive at the contradiction b-S-b and not (b-S-b) you close the scope of the assumption by concluding the barber doesn't exist.

If you are using it as an assumption and then discharge it then your initial sentence should not include "there is a barber".

The whole thing is an assumption.  There can be no paradoxes.  So there has to be an open scope of an assumption, that you must close, to get if X then Y and not Y.  Then by RAA, you conclude not X.

See Barber paradox: "The sentence says that a barber x exists. Its truth value is false, as the existential clause is unsatisfiable (a contradiction) because of the universal quantifier. Since the sentence is false for the biconditional, the entire universal clause is false. Since the existential clause is a conjunction with one operand that is false, the entire sentence is false."

If you want to be fussy, you should make clear that the barber is an individual who is within the domain that the 'all' quantifies over. Otherwise you could avoid the paradox by saying that the barber is a robot and the 'all' extends over the domain of people in the town.

To make an interpretation of the logical structure we assume that All is . The set of x is not empty. In syllogistic there is no such assumption. In predicate logic it's different. But All cannot be instantiated by the constant 'barber'. So the interpretation of the formula in the town doesn't satisfy it unless 'barber' is excluded from the se of all citizens of the town. That's all.

No paradox, it's simple:  The barber just goes to another town to either shave or get shaved...


So my question is what is the exact meanings of 'all' and 'only' used to arrive at the paradox?

"All and only" in that problem statement (in that "setup") just means all those men and nothing but those men.  In fact, "all and only" is standard parlance, especially in logic and mathematics, and corresponds to an if and only if.
That said, to be precise, it is not the meaning of "all and only" that gets us the conclusion, it just concurs to a formalization of the problem statement, namely that (forall S, exists b s.t.) forall x, bSx <-> ~xSx.  Getting to resolution takes 1) recognizing/guessing that we can prove there is no such b; and 2) few steps to prove that much (constructive steps suffice, we do not need classical axiom to prove the result; nor we need assume the town is non-empty).

I'm thinking 'all' has existential import, while 'any' does not.

No, "all" and "any" are just informal and only a logical analysis can tell what is exactly meant by a natural language statement.  As for formal logic, mathematical or otherwise, a universal quantifier is just a universal quantifier, there are no distinctions.
(Some logics or contexts assume a non-empty universe of discourse, in which case one might say universal quantification has "existential import": but in those contexts all universal quantifications have such import, not just some.)


In a certain town there is a barber who shaves all those who don't shave themselves,

∀x(¬xSx -> bSx)

and only those who don't shave themselves.

∀x(xSx -> ¬bSx), or, ∀x(bSx -> ¬xSx), which classicaly is the same

So my question is what is the exact meanings of 'all' and 'only' used to arrive at the paradox?

'all' is just the usual universal quantification; 'only' is a bit subtler: in natural language it seems to be saying something directly about the objects/individuals, but in the usual formalization it says something about the (direction of the) implication, which is probably where some confusion/weirdness stems from

@AC15-could it be, that the exact meaning of the barber shaves all those who don't shave themselves is: &exists; x[~(x-S-x)] ∧ ∀ x[if ~(x-S-x) then b-S-x], and the exact meaning of the barber shaves only those who don't shave themselves is there exists an x, such that  b-S-x, and for any x if b-S-x then not(x-S-x)?

“All” is everybody. What can be unexpected to people is that “all” of zero is zero.
“Any” is at least one. “Any” in a group of zero is not possible. “Any” in a group of 1 is also “all”. “Some” is the same as “any”.

All men are mortal means for any x: if x is a man then x is mortal, and there exists a man.  Any man is mortal means for any x: if x is a man then x is mortal.  The former has existential import, the latter does not.  At least in my manner of interpretation.

The question is about "all" and "only", not "all" and "any".
